# Cannot execute script after installing SELinux

Tags: files, security, selinux

I have script in `/home/ubuntu/bin/` which I have added to the `PATH` variable.

After installing SeLinux and enabling it in permissive mode it (`SELINUX=permissive` `in`/etc/selinux/config`), I am unable to run those script if they are excutable

```
# myscript
myscript : �s">������^��~�/bin/bash
```

Security context:

```
# ls -Z myscript
system_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0 myscript*
```

File type:

```
# file -Z myscript
ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=########################################, stripped
```

**How can I run my script and avoid this error with SELinux in permissive mode?**

Answer (score 0):

The bash script were compiled before installing SELinux with `shc -f myscript` (script compiled with SELinux enabled are working).

I simply recompile my script with SELinux enabled.